# upload multiple images at once

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I found this piece of code on site https://makitweb.com/multiple-files-upload-at-once-with-php/

For some reason $countfiles only counts up to 20 and allows to upload 20 files no matter the size.
If i change $countfiles = 50; just for test it stops working.

```
 $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Even doing DEMO on the site it shows (Choose Files 24 files)
Pressing upload shows 20 items.

Comment: Check your php.ini file, it has a variable as `max_file_uploads` that is by default set as 20 increase that value as per your requirements.

Comment: Okei Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to PHP documentation for [file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)

**Increase max_file_uploads**

By default you'll see this

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads=20
```

Also you can update these values,

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```